# Error: BackendHttpSetting when adding HTTP setting in gateway using app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, gateway

I try to add a **HTTP setting** to my Azure gateway, using HTTPS protocol and click yes for **use for a App service** to yes, but this error show up every time i try to save.

**Failed to save configuration changes to application gateway 'X-applicationgateway'. Error: BackendHttpSetting X-applicationgateway/test must reference authentication certificate. Either all BackendHttpSettings must reference authentication certificate, or none of them should.**

But i dont understand the error, because when you choose yes for the option **use for a App service**, you can't even choose/reate a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PowerShell to create Trusted Root certificate.

Here is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-end-to-end-ssl-powershell#create-an-application-gateway-configuration-object

To add to this when you try to add new https setting with trusted root certificate while there is another https setting already existing without it. Try by removing existing setting and adding it again with cert.